# Error: ( /bin/sh: 1: {node,: not found ) when trying to run docker image

Tags: node.js, docker

I've recently installed docker and I'm just trying to test out whether or not everything is running. I've already built the image and I'm just trying to run a basic node.js application but when whenever try running: `docker run -p PortNumber ImageName` I get an error saying `/bin/sh: 1: {node,: not found`

My docker file:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

Expose 3000

CMD [ "node", "app.mjs" ]
```

.js file

```
import express from 'express';

import connectToDatabase from './helpers.mjs'

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h2>Hi there!</h2>');
});

await connectToDatabase();

app.listen(3000);
```

and

```
const connectToDatabase = () => {
  const dummyPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });

  return dummyPromise;
};

export default connectToDatabase;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Double check the CMD string and make sure it's exactly what you've included here.

Comment: @BMitch, I’ve copy pasted the Dockerfile directly from VS code. And I just checked, it’s the same thing

Comment: The error doesn't match the included text. Try taking only what you've shown in this question into a directory, run only the commands shown here, and verify you can reproduce your error. See [mcve] for more details.